# Ajax call not received by rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

my Ajax call via jQuery will always be transmitted (status 200), but only sometimes it's received by the rails controller. Means the data is  sent properly but most times the controller sends back an empty json object as the response. I need the timeout else the stringify doesn't  work. Any hints?

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "homepage/routes",
        data: {
          routes_my: JSON.stringify(routes)
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }, 100);
  }

#Controller
      def routes
        @routes = JSON.parse(params\[:routes_my\], object_class: OpenStruct)
        render :json => @routes
      end
```

[console log working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPf3l.png)

[console log bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzCWf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that "routes" is the result of an async function and was sometimes only partially available. Fixed that by calling the Ajax as a callback function. setTimeout is then irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = JSON.stringify(routes);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "homepage/routes",
            data: {routes_my: obj},
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
});
```

Comment: Then I get  "no implicit conversion of nil into String" from the controller

Comment: I have updated my code can you please check if it works? @charly1212

Comment: Then I get an object with an empty table   {"table":{}} as response from from the controller :/